# Contiki OS - can I have multiple etimer?

Tags: process, contiki

Can I have 2 different etimer's in 2 different processes, in Contiki OS ?
Or are there some restrictions with the use of etimer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. Active `etimers` are stored in a linked list in the system, so there are no restriction on how many you can have, the only limiting factor is RAM size.

Additionally, for a really large number of etimers (e.g. tens of them) you'll run into efficiency issues, as the `etimer` implementation is not optimized for algorithmic complexity: all of adding, removing, and firing a timer is done in `O(n)` time, where `n` is the number of etimers.